# Making call to server when application is in background in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to make http request to web server periodically say after every 10 secs.

I am using Timer in application which makes http call. Now when application goes to background when user press Windows key.. the timer stops

Can I continue making call to web server?

I referred the VOID chatter box application, but looks like it is for VOIP application only.

Regards,

SRS

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows phone 8: how to check if there are new messages on the database (server) all the time (even if the app is not running)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589017/windows-phone-8-how-to-check-if-there-are-new-messages-on-the-database-server)

Comment: you can not poll in background every 10 sec. Periodic tasks limited to 30 min intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a `TaskAgent` that inherits from `ScheduledTaskAgent` and override `OnInvoke()` method. You also need to add the task into WMAppManifest.xml

```
<Deployment ...>
...
  <App ...>
    ...
    <Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />
      <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
        <BackgroundServiceAgent Name="YourTaskAgent" Type="YourNameSpace.YourTaskAgent" Source="YourTaskAgent" Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" />
      </ExtendedTask>
    </Tasks>
  ...
  </App>
...
</Deployment>
```

Your main application itself cannot continue to perform HTTP requests when it is suspended. For more info see [MSDN on background tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). However, keep in mind that Background Tasks have limitations in what they can do. Hope this helps.